# How to update list of remote branches using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know that I can use built-in terminal and do something like:

```
git remote update origin --prune
```

But I'm curious whether or not it's possible to do this using only IDEA UI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call `VCS -> Git -> Fetch`, or `VCS -> Update project`, since fetch is done as a part of it. It executes `git fetch --all`, so the effect should be the same.